# JQGRID - Delete the row with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

How to delete row in JQGrid with button

http://jsfiddle.net/chandelyt/w4oudhh4/3/

**HTML**

```
<table id="list2">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="jQGridDemoPager"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var $j = $.noConflict(true);
var mydata = [
  { "UserName": "8125579231", "RoleId": 1, "Name": "John", "RoleName": "Administrator" },
  { "UserName": "9676078986", "RoleId": 1, "Name": "Mia", "RoleName": "Administrator" },
  { "UserName": "9703804807", "RoleId": 1, "Name": "Shan", "RoleName": "Administrator" },
  { "UserName": "9177458358", "RoleId": 1, "Name": "Tim", "RoleName": "Administrator" },
  { "UserName": "7760699118", "RoleId": 2, "Name": "Harry", "RoleName": "Sales" }
];


$j('#list2').jqGrid({
  caption: "Employee Details",
  data: mydata,
  datatype: "local",
  colNames: ["UserName", "RoleId", "Name", "RoleName","Delete"],
  colModel: [
    { name: "UserName", index: 'UserName', width: 150 },
    { name: 'RoleId', index: "RoleId", width: 150 },
    { name: "Name", index: "Name", width: 150 },
    { name: "RoleName", index: "RoleName", width: 150 },
    { name: 'Delete', formatter: buttonFormatter }
  ],
  rowNum: 10,
  pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
  sortname: "UserName",
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "desc",
});


function buttonFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  return '<button type="button" onClick=clickFunction1();>Delete</button>';
};

function clickFunction1() {

  var grid = $j('#list2');
  var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
  var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'Name');
  alert("Selected  Name: " + myCellData);

};
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: silver; }
```

Issue as below:
When i click delete button (without selecting row) it shows previously selected rows value (Name in this case)

I want to click on any button (and it should select that row -- or not) and get its fields value.. which I post to server for deletion and then refresh the grid once item is deleted.

It is working if I select a row and then click button ... Working my local copy but not on fiddle... might be becasue of old version of fiddeler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the function `buttonFormatter`, which you calls inside of `onClick` have to be **global** function (the property of the global `window` object). Seconds, I would recommend you to forward `this`, which is the clicked `td` element to `clickFunction1` function:

```
function buttonFormatter() {
    return '<button type="button" onClick="clickFunction1.call(this)">Delete</button>';
}
```

and then use `$j(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` to get the `rowid` of the clicked row:

```
function clickFunction1() {
    var grid = $j('#list2'), rowid = $j(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Name');
    alert("Selected  Name: " + myCellData);
}
```

You will see the results on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w4oudhh4/12/

Alternatively you can use simplified version of the custom formatter:

```
function buttonFormatter() {
    return '<button type="button">Delete</button>';
}
```

where **no** `onClick` is used. jqGrid register already `click` event handler on the grid. If the user click on the `"Delete"` button then the `click` event handler of the *parent outer* element will be called because of the [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow). jqGrid provides `beforeSelectRow` callback which will be called inside of `click` event handler. The `target` property of the event is `<td>` element, which is clicked. Thus one can use

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var grid = $j(this), rowid = $j(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Name');
    alert("Selected  Name: " + myCellData);
    return true; // allows selection of the row
}
```

see another demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/w4oudhh4/13/

Answer (score 1):

Complete working code for delete row wise:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4oudhh4/159/

```
function clickFunction1() {
     $('#list2').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` to Delete button and remove `onClick=clickFunction1();` like this :

```
return '<button class="dlt" type="button">Delete</button>';
```

And jQuery like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dlt").on("click",function(){

        $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    })

})
```